# Android Google Maps v2 polyline 3d effect

Tags: android, google-maps

How do I achieve the 3d polyline effect on Android Google maps API v2 that is used by the Google Maps app for Navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoogleMaps uses their own way to render polyline (not via [`Polyline`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes#polylines)). There are 2 possible ways to achieve something similar:

1) Use regular `Polyline` class and draw 2 polylines - thicker one (let's say 10px width) and thiner one (8px) on top. You won't get the same visual effect as in GoogleMap app, but you will get much better sense of real object rather than plain polyline

2) Use custom [`TileOverlay`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/tileoverlay#add), so you will be in charge of rendering your polyline. This approach is much more complicated, but that's what I had to implement in one of my apps since default look-and-feel of polyline was not acceptable. You can look at [map util lib](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/TileProviderAndProjectionDemo.java) to get general understanding how to implement custom overlay